# When will the tabId change

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome Extension capturing all of the web data. 
I just found that the change to address bar can lead to a tabId change. Anyone has a full idea about when there is a change to the tabId?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By no means authoritative answer:

It has to do with pre-rendering, and that specific case may have to do with Instant search.
As you type in the address bar, Chrome apparently pre-fetches and pre-renders some pages for faster navigation.
Even if you do not trigger this via address bar, Chrome still can do tab swapping for performance reasons.

Consider the [description of `chrome.tabs.onReplaced`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onReplaced):

> Fired when a tab is replaced with another tab due to prerendering or instant.

Or, [this remark](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#tab_ids) in `chrome.webNavigation` API docs:

> Not all navigating tabs correspond to actual tabs in Chrome's UI, e.g., a tab that is being pre-rendered. Such tabs are not accessible via the tabs API nor can you request information about them via `webNavigation.getFrame` or `webNavigation.getAllFrames`. Once such a tab is swapped in, an onTabReplaced event is fired and they become accessible via these APIs.

---

### To summarize:

For performance reasons Chrome can spawn a separate, invisible tab, and swap an existing tab with this pre-rendered tab.

If that happens, a `chrome.tabs.onReplaced` event is dispatched, providing old and new `tabId`s.

Comment: Thanks!!! Can I ask one more question: what if I disable the prerendering feature in Chrome, will it get rid of the tabId swapping conflict?

Comment: What "conflict"? Besides, while you can disable it for yourself, if you publish your extension it's unreasonable to ask that of your users.

Comment: TabId swapping. Will the tabId be stable when the prerendering is turned off? I will just disable it for local test.

Comment: To answer that, I don't know. You've got to test it (also switch off Instant search). But it makes more sense to work your logic around it by either not keeping `tabId`s, or updating them on `onReplaced`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! Thanks for all of these!! really helpful!